# responsive style menu button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, responsive-design

I hope someone can help, I am fairly new to WPF and want to create a button that looks like the menu button in mobile Apps and on responsive web applications, that is a square button with three horizontal lines.

I have tried creating a button with a canvas and three lines but this does not work correctly.

Can anyone suggest the XAML that could achieve this please?

**EDIT**

I have added the code in to my application from the answer, the XAML is below

```
<Button x:Name="systemButton" IsTabStop="False" Style="{StaticResource LightWindowButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button.Content>
        <Grid Width="31" Height="23" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Path Data="M8,8 L28,8" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="4" StrokeThickness="4" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Path Data="M8,8 L28,8" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="4" StrokeThickness="4" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" />
            <Path Data="M8,8 L28,8" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="4" StrokeThickness="4" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" />
        </Grid>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

In my `AeroWindow` class I am getting the instance of the button and binding to the click event as below

```
var systemButton = this.GetTemplateChild("systemButton") as Button;
if (systemButton != null)
{
    systemButton.Click += this.SystemButtonOnClick;
}
```

But the event handler never gets fired when I click the button. I have checked and `systemButton` is not `null` therefore the `Click` event gets bound to the event handler, the breakpoint on the event handler never gets hit through. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your content in the Button, and for that you apply a content template.

```
<Window.Resources>  


    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid Width="51" Height="42">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="#FF2DBE29" Height="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="#FF2DBE29" Height="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="#FF2DBE29" Height="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="#FF2DBE29" Height="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3"/>
            <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="#FF2DBE29" Height="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="4"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate> 


</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}">
    <Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Height="48"
     ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}"/>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,88,232,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="67" Height="56">

        <Button.Content>
            <Grid Width="51" Height="42">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="#FF2DBE29"  Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center" StrokeThickness="5"/>
            <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="#FF2DBE29"  Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" StrokeThickness="5"/>
            <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="#FF2DBE29"  Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" StrokeThickness="5"/>
            <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="#FF2DBE29"  Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" StrokeThickness="5"/>
            <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="#FF2DBE29"  Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="4" StrokeThickness="5"/>
        </Grid>
        </Button.Content>           
        </Button>
```

I have updated my answer. In DataTemplate we are using Height, and in next Button we are using only StrokeThickness.

And for using style you can do following changes :

```
<Window.Resources>  

        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid Width="51" Height="42">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PathFillBrush" Color="#FF2DBE29"/>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="{DynamicResource PathFillBrush}" Height="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="{DynamicResource PathFillBrush}" Height="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="{DynamicResource PathFillBrush}" Height="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2"/>
                <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="{DynamicResource PathFillBrush}" Height="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3"/>
                <Path Data="M0,5 L51,5" Fill="{DynamicResource PathFillBrush}" Height="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2DC65A" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="4"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>         

        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}"/>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, the lines come out thin (like 1px) in my application, how is it possible to change this, i assume Height would that be correct? also how can you bind the Fill and Stroke to the values specified in the template. Also how would i apply the same in a <Style/>, sorry for the million questions

Comment: @Neil Ask separate questions, as there are others too who use this site. This is a good practice. Anyway, for thin lines : Use StrokeThickness=5 in above example that will make lines good enough and remove Height completely.